# Input button can't unbold text

Tags: css, forms, input

http://stepladderuk.com/dev/wedding/exp/

The text in the input button is bold, which I don't want.

I can't work out what's making it bold.

When I inspect the element, I come up with font-weight:100 as I declared in the CSS.

I tried -webkit-appearance: none;

this creates a strange behaviour where the text only unbolds when you hover.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>

        <!-- meta stuff -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Matt &amp; Caroline</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Description here">
        <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">

        <!--FONT LINKAGE -->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fast.fonts.net/cssapi/c020518f-a748-4829-83c4-9cd0e83dd476.css"/>

        <!-- Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAOJWH6GtBIMO1GGByFIf3A9Q6nEe050L0"></script>







    </head>
    <body class="homepage">




        <!--IE notice -->
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->













        <section id="rsvp">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="heading-holder">
                    <div class="heading-inner">
                        <img class="arrow-left" src="img/arrow-right.png" alt="arrow">
                            <h1>rsvp</h1>
                            <img class="arrow-right" src="img/arrow-left.png" alt="arrow">
                    </div>
                </div>




                <div class="inner">


                        <form action="MAILTO:bz@stepladderuk.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

                            <div class="col col-wide">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-row" for="name">Names of everyone in your party</label>
                                    <span class="form-row text-small">Please seperate names with a comma.</span>
                                    <input class="form-row" type="text" name="name">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-row" for="number">Your phone number</label>
                                    <input class="form-row" type="text" name="number">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-row" for="email">Your email address</label>
                                    <input class="form-row" type="text" name="email">
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-row" for="dietary-requirements">Special dietary requirements</label>
                                    <input class="form-row" type="text" name="dietary-requirements">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-row" for="song">Favourite song</label>
                                    <input class="form-row" type="text" name="song">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-row" for="transport">Transport</label>
                                    <span class="form-row text-small">Please indicate if travelling by coach whether you will need transport to the venue and which coach you will return on</span>
                                    <input class="form-row" type="text" name="transport">
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="clear"></div>

                            <hr class="hr-2-em" />

                            <p>
                                <span class="text-small">
                                    Please fill out this form, click send and send the automatically generated email.
                                </span>
                            </p>


                            <div class="col-wide">
                                <div class="link-style-2 center">
                                    <span class="left-edge"></span>
                                        <input class="text" type="submit" value="Send It!">
                                    <span class="right-edge"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>



                </div><!-- end inner -->

                </div><!-- end container -->

        <div class="clear"></div>
        </section>



    </body>
</html>
```

CSS;

```
form{
    z-index:100;
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    .form-group{
        margin-bottom:2em;
    }
    .form-row{
        display:block;
    }

    input[type=text]{
        border:0;
        background-color:white;
        padding:.4em;
        width:100%;
        font-family:$font-main, georgia, serif;
        width:100%;
        margin-top:.2em;
    }
    input[type=submit]{
        font-family:$font-main, georgia, serif;
        border:0;
        font-weight:100;
        -webkit-appearance: none!important;
    }
}
```

Does this in all browsers except IE. I'm on a mac.

This is how it looks;

[image: this is the problem, too bold]

This is how it should look (this is another button on the website, but it's just a plain link, not a form input element)

[image: How it should look]

I'm pretty certain the problem is because it's an input.

Comment: please share your code in the question itself, more info here : [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It’s not bold on Chrome, Firefox, or IE. It’s regular weight, fake italic. Apparently the cause is outside the part of code posted. Please provide code that actually reproduces the issue. And post CSS code, or at least specify which non-CSS tool you are using in your stylesheet-like code.

Comment: Added entire page code.

Comment: The CSS is SASS. It's not fake italic, the font is loaded from fonts.com. When I viewed it in IE8 it IS fake italic, I guess because the browser doesn't support embedded fonts. Anyway, I don't think that's the problem, as you can see in the screenshot I posted, the bottom one is how it should work. Exactly same styling, only difference is it's an input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix.

```
input{
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

You need to add `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` to the input.

If you've added this to the html or body element, this rule will work on every element on the page except for inputs, so you need to redeclare it.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you apply normal?

```
input{
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Tried this but made no difference.

Comment: using !important? `font-weight: normal !important;`

Comment: ummm, that might be  different due to font-size, so set font-size too.